# How can I expose JBoss AS 7 server logs so that they are visible and available on the web page to download?

Tags: java, logging, jar, jboss7.x, war

I am basically looking to expose JBOSS AS 7 server logs. I need to make sure that the logs are downloadable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiair with a method within JBOSS to do so, but you can use apache httpd. Install and configure it in either of the following ways:
* expose the logging directory as a directory listing using httpd.conf, make sure to use .htaccess to provide some authentication.
* create a PHP / static HTML to only expose the log files you want to.

In both cases you want to use IP listing, or a firewall, to restrict access.